# Calling pdb.set_trace from script invoked from os.system

Tags: python, pdb

I want to debug a python script which is invoked via `os.system()` from another python script. I tried calling `pdb.set_trace` from the invoked code but it doesn't work. I can't see the Python pdb prompt.

---

Its sort of automation framework. My final python script where i want to put set_trace is like:

`python script1.py --invokes--> script2.py --invokes--> script3.py (Here, in script3.py my set_trace is )`

I'm working on linux with python 2.4

Comment: If it's being invoked using os.system, you can invoke it straight from the shell yourself. Can't you?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Is stdout perhaps redirected?

Comment: @codeape : thanks !! Yes , i was using redirection.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've added an answer (so you can mark it as accepted if you wish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using output redirection, the pdb prompt will be redirected as well.